# Making coordinate system with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, subfig

[image: expected result]

I have a problem with making these signals with `TikZ` package. Can someone explain `TikZ` package, how it works and how I can start with making this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE :) Please have a look at the [description](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/subfig) of the `subfig` package. It is used to place multiple "small" figures into a single `figure` environment. Since you ask about a coordinate system and signals, I assume you are more interested in the `tikz` package. You can find lots of examples for creating such pictures using `tikz` on the Internet and on TeX.SE.

Comment: The best explanation how `tikz` package works you can find in its documentation ( *TikZ & PGF Manual for Version 3.1.9a* and much shorter unofficial description *A very minimal introduction to TikZ*, both you can find on CTAN). Many examples of `tikzpicture` you can find on https://texample.net//

Comment: @Unknown While your assumption about TikZ may be correct, I personally don't think you should edit a question in that way without knowing that the edit actually represents what the OP wants. It would be better to ask for clarification and let the OP edit, or at the very least confirm your assumption in a comment before you edit.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to draw these coordinate systems and signals, here is an example how you can do it:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}  % curly brace

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        thick,
        arrow/.style={
            -Latex
        }
    ]

        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        % First Graphic
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

        % coordinate system
        \draw[arrow] (-1.25,0) -- node[at end, below] {$\phi_1(t)$} (5,0);
        \draw[arrow] (0,-1.25) -- node[at end, left] {$\phi_2(t)$} (0,5);

        % red and blue arrow
        \draw[arrow, draw=red]  (0,0) -- node[midway, above] {$s_1$} (4,0);
        \draw[arrow, draw=blue] (0,0) -- node[midway, right] {$s_2$} (0,4);

        % dashed line
        \draw[dashed] (4,0) -- node[midway, above right] {$\sqrt{2 E_b}$} (0,4);

        % curly braces
        \draw [decorate, decoration={brace, mirror, amplitude=6pt}] (.15,-.25) -- node[midway, below=.25cm] {$\sqrt{E_b}$} (3.85,-.25);
        \draw [decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=6pt}] (-.25,.15) -- node[midway, left=.25cm] {$\sqrt{E_b}$} (-.25,3.85);
            
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
        % Second Graphic
        %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

        \begin{scope}[xshift=11.5cm]
            % coordinate system
            \draw[arrow] (-5,0) -- node[at end, below] {$\phi_1(t)$} (5,0);
            \draw[arrow] (0,-1.25) -- node[at end, left] {$\phi_2(t)$} (0,2);

            % red and blue arrow
            \draw[arrow, draw=red]  (0,0) -- node[midway, above] {$s_1$} (4,0);
            \draw[arrow, draw=blue] (0,0) -- node[midway, above] {$s_2$} (-4,0);

            % curly braces
            \draw [decorate, decoration={brace, mirror, amplitude=6pt}] (.15,-.25) -- node[midway, below=.25cm] {$\sqrt{E_b}$} (3.85,-.25);
            \draw [decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=6pt}] (-.15,-.25) -- node[midway, below=.25cm] {$\sqrt{E_b}$} (-3.85,-.25);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]